# How can I specifically convert this php code to html?

Tags: php, html

how can I specifically convert this php below code to html? I want to do this as I want to be able to run this code on my website.

From reading other forum posts I understand about people saying them link the PHP file externally using something like this  `<ahref="hello.php">php</a>`. However, from my understanding my PHP code is slightly different in terms of the output and I'm just not sure.

Below is my php code I want to run externally on my site from the html file.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser = get_browser();
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Comment: If all you care about is what browser they are using, there is no reason to even use php. You can do this with straight javascript on the front end. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

Comment: I have to use PHP as a requirement.

Comment: @LiamDocherty That seems silly.

Comment: ___from the html file___ If the file is a `.html` then PHP wont run anyway!

Comment: @RiggsFolly 100% sure of that? It'll run, only if.... well, you know :p

Comment: I was only trying to get some help of course you lot love being keyboard warriors. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use Ajax and show the result in HTML

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  urL:"./tomy.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:{getuserAgent:1},
  success:function(data){
  $("#mydiv").html(data);
  }

});


</script>
```

tomy.php

```
    <?php
   if(isset($_POST['getuserAgent']){
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $browser = get_browser();
    print_r($browser);
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks so much. Can I please ask where the toy.php came from?

Comment: it's the place where your result came from when you generate the user agent result that result send back to your HTML page and using javascript you are rendering that result. better if use json if you dealing with arrays before continuing with the answer please refer this from top to bottom [https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp]

Comment: when we dealing with Ajax php functioning separately and it's execute only when request tomy.php is the file that do your stuff in your situation it's get the user agent and send user agent data.since you can't use .php we have use Ajax. JavaScript can use in html we are calling tomy.php and get result using JavaScript and displaying what has came back from .php actually i don't know how much knowledge you have with php and ajax if you have no idea  in this area i recommend please do  some tutorial because now it's rare only using php now days we always use Ajax and PHP both together